# installing zmq module on redHat linux RHEL 6.2 64bit machine

Tags: installation, zeromq, rhel

Hi I am trying to install zmq module on a linux machine.Below are the steps that i followed

```
•   Make sure you have the following packages installed (sudo apt-get install binutils libtool autoconf automake)
•   Get the latest POSIX tarball (http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software) and untar it  
•   Run configure (./configure)
•   Run make (sudo make install)
•   npm install zmq or npm update if you already have it listed in your package.json
•   sudo ldconfig (otherwise you might get the error "connot open shared object file")
```

But when i ran the above steps i got the error as below

```
Error: libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/MLIDeployment/MLI/zeromq-4.0.3/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:8:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I'm stuck here any  help regarding this will be much helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is that `libzmq.so` cannot not found.

You need to add the install directory (defaults to `/usr/local/lib`) to LD_PATH.

To add it you need to execute:

```
sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local-lib.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Hope this works.